Proof of a method of calculating the ideal quotient $I:\langle f^{\infty}\rangle$
Background:
(1) Let $I$ be an ideal of $K[x_1,...,x_n]$, and let $f\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $K$ is a field.
We define $$I:f^{\infty}:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}I:\langle f^i\rangle.$$
And I have known that $\exists m\in \mathbb N$ such that $I:f^{\infty}=I:\langle f^m\rangle$ by observing that $I=I:\langle 1\rangle\subset I:\langle f\rangle\subset\cdots.$
(2) Let $w$ be a new variable, let $J=\langle I,1-wf\rangle\subset K[x_1,...,x_n,w]$ we have $I:f^{\infty}=J\cap K[x_1,...,x_n,w]$.
The question is: Let $\{f_1,...,f_s\}$ and $\{g_1,...,g_t\}$ be a generating set for $I$ and $J\cap K[x_1,...,x_n,w]$ respectively.
Write $g_i(x)=(1-wf)h_i(x,w)+\sum_{j=1}^{s}u_{ij}(x,w)f_j,i=1,..,t $$\quad$And we define $m:=\max_{ij}(\deg_w(u_{ij}))$
How to prove that:$I:f^{\infty}=I:\langle f^m\rangle$?
Additional explanations:

I write $x$  to represent $(x_1,...,x_n) $, and $h(x,w)$ means the polynomial depend on both $(x_1,... x_n)$ and $w$.
$\deg_w(u_{ij})$ means the highest degree of $w$ in the terms of a polynomial, for example: $f=x_1w^7+x_1x_2^8$, then $\deg_wf=7$.

Here is my attempt: I try to prove $$I:\langle f^{m+1}\rangle\subset I:\langle f^m\rangle$$
by considering $g\in I:\langle f^{m+1}\rangle$, we can write $g=\sum_{i=1}^t q_ig_i=\sum_{i=1}^t q_i[(1-wf)h_i(x,w)+\sum_{j=1}^{s}u_{ij}(x,w)f_j]$, and since $g$ is not depend on the variable $w$, i try to set some value for $w=0$ or $w=1$, but it doesn't seem to work.
I also find it hard to combine the condition:$g\in I:\langle f^{m+1}\rangle$ and $m:=\max_{ij}(\deg_w(u_{ij}))$.
What really confuse me is:How does the $m$ defined above work?

The question comes from An Introduction to Grobner Bases by  William W. Adams and Philippe Loustaunau, page 75, Exercise 2.3.14.


The problem can be solved by putting $w = 1/f$; notice in that case, the expression for $g$ will be $g = \sum_{i,j} q_iu_{ij}(x,1/f)f_j$. It is clear that $f^mg \in I$.
I have not written the solution completely so you can complete it yourself.
